# Multiple Values for One Day

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-cleaning, forecasting, forecast

I have two questions.

1- I have weather data of 10 turbines and I know their collective production(Power).I also know maximum power a turbine can make. How can I forecast collective production if I know individual turbine weather condition?

Power Data

```
    Time                       Power Produced(MW)        
    2010-11-11 00:00:00+00:00     248.367512
```

Weather Data

```
time    Temperature     RelativeHumidity    Wind_U  Wind_V    Pressure  CloudCover  WindGustSpeed   latitude    longitude
2010-11-11  80.060944    0.959463         4.791473  3.756961    99201.50    0.999969    9.061006    55.003349   9.983611
```

2- Moreover, I have more than one value for one hour weather like 2010-11-11 (100F 30.3m/s) ,and there is another set of values for same date like 2010-11-11 (99.8F 30.1m/s). How can I use those multiple values for single date?

Comment: The first questions. It can be modeled using Multivariate Time Series, search you will find many tutorials online. For the second questions, how do you have more than one value for one hour? Maybe data is recorded hourly but you are looking at daily data? If that is the case, you may want to do daily mean aggregations to reduce noises.

Comment: @TwinPenguins thanks for your reply. I will take a look at multivariate time series. No I have more than one value for same hour. I was wondering is there any way of utilizing all those values at once. What I can think of is, may be , I can make multiple models utilizing different data.